# Adding color to multiple regression lines in a doubly nested lapply

Tags: r, plot, colors, regression, lapply

I'm trying to make a plot of multiple regression lines on each single plot in a panel.  So far, I have it that I can get the title of each panel and regression lines in each panel.  However, I am having some trouble adding color to the regression lines.

```
set.seed(1)
abc.df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 1000), col2 = rep(1:4, 750),
                      col3 = rnorm(3000), col4 = rnorm(3000, 2))
names(abc.df) <- c("factor1", "factor2", "q", "value")
abc.df$factor1 <- as.factor(abc.df$factor1)
abc.df$factor2 <- as.factor(abc.df$factor2)
abc_list <- split(abc.df, abc.df$factor1)
namelist <- names(abc_list)
colorlist <- c("red", "green", "blue", "orange") 
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
lapply(names(abc_list), function(x) {
  plot(abc_list[[x]]$q, abc_list[[x]]$value, pch = 20, 
       col = adjustcolor(colorlist, alpha = 0.3),
       xlab = "q", ylab = "Value", main = x);
  newsplit <- split(abc_list[[x]], abc_list[[x]]$factor2);
  lapply(names(newsplit), function(y){
    abline(lm(value ~ q, newsplit[[y]], col = colorlist[y]))
  })})
```

However, I get warnings saying that the code doesn't know how to handle the col argument, so it ignores it.  How can I fix my logic?

And yes, I know I could use ggplot2, but I'm trying to figure it out in base graphics.

EDIT: OK, so new problem.  I'm changing factor2 to words instead of numbers, as such:

```
set.seed(1)
abc.df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 1000), 
                      col2 = rep(c("one","two","three","four"), 750),
                      col3 = rnorm(3000), col4 = rnorm(3000, 2))
names(abc.df) <- c("factor1", "factor2", "q", "value")
abc.df$factor1 <- as.factor(abc.df$factor1)
abc.df$factor2 <- as.factor(abc.df$factor2)
abc_list <- split(abc.df, abc.df$factor1)
namelist <- names(abc_list)
library(RColorBrewer)
colorlist <- brewer.pal(4, "Set1")
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
lapply(names(abc_list), function(x) {
  plot(abc_list[[x]]$q, abc_list[[x]]$value, pch = 20, 
       col = adjustcolor(colorlist, alpha = 0.3),
       xlab = "q", ylab = "Value", main = x);
  newsplit <- split(abc_list[[x]], abc_list[[x]]$factor2);
  lapply(names(newsplit), function(y) {
    abline(lm(value ~ q, newsplit[[y]]), col = colorlist[as.integer(y)])
  })})
```

This generates 12 warnings of this variety:

```
1: In int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf,  ... :
  NAs introduced by coercion
```

So the solution is only good for when the factor is a number string, not a character string.  How do I rectify this?

Comment: In `abline(lm(value ~ q, newsplit[[y]], col = colorlist[y]))`, you are giving `col` argument to `lm`.  Close one of the parenthesis before `col`, then no warning.

Comment: Thanks, but what that then does is not plot the lines at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could somehow figure out that `y` in your last line is character, and thus does not work as index.  An easy fix is to convert it to integer.

```
set.seed(1)
abc.df <- data.frame(col1 = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 1000), col2 = rep(1:4, 750),
                     col3 = rnorm(3000), col4 = rnorm(3000, 2))
names(abc.df) <- c("factor1", "factor2", "q", "value")
abc.df$factor1 <- as.factor(abc.df$factor1)
abc.df$factor2 <- as.factor(abc.df$factor2)
abc_list <- split(abc.df, abc.df$factor1)
namelist <- names(abc_list)
colorlist <- c("red", "green", "blue", "orange") 
par(mfrow = c(1, 3))
lapply(names(abc_list), function(x) {
  plot(abc_list[[x]]$q, abc_list[[x]]$value, pch = 20, 
       col = adjustcolor(colorlist, alpha = 0.3),
       xlab = "q", ylab = "Value", main = x);
  newsplit <- split(abc_list[[x]], abc_list[[x]]$factor2);
  lapply(names(newsplit), function(y){
    abline(lm(value ~ q, newsplit[[y]]), col = colorlist[as.integer(y)])
  })})
```

Comment: Interesting.  I guess that's because the vector was a character vector and not an index like in the first use of colorlist for an argument?  Thanks. +1

Comment: OK, I figured it out.  I had to make sure col was reading from the new list itself:
`col = colorlist[newsplit[[y]]$factor2]`